# Howto Windows 7 network logon Prompt

Tags: windows-7, networking, login

In my university we have user accounts for all students, when we go to the computer centre, we have windows xp computers and the network login prompt is shown by default. I want to login with my windows 7 laptop. How do I get the network login prompt on my laptop.

We have access to ethernet cables so getting on the network is not an issue.
I'm running windows 7 home premium that came preloaded with my PC.

As a side question, could I also login using linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, your university is running a domain service.  Home premium does not come with the ability to join a domain, so you are SOL there.

You can however, usually be able to access those network resources.  Depending how it is setup, you can fire up a command prompt using 'runas /netonly /user: *studentlogin* cmd.exe` and can access their file shares and or databases.

You can't do that with Explorer though, since AFAIK you can't spin off a whole nother explorer process.

Comment: So is there no way i could possibly do it.
Will running a virtual machine using windows xp professional help?

Comment: Nope. You'll need permission to join the university domain, which requires Domain Admin credentials.  I probably should of asked this first.  Why do you want the prompt in the first place??  What do you need access to that the computer labs do?

Comment: The computer labs are accessible only for a limited time from 0600 hrs in the morning to 2200 hrs in the evening.
We're in a technical group so we have a Room with ancient Pentium 3 computers, We'd want to use the lan cable there with our laptops.

Comment: Specifically we have NAS(network attached storage) with our university accounts and that can only be accessed by logging into the lab computers. If there's another way to do this, kindly let me know.

Comment: Depending on how the NAS is setup.  I could speculate, but I will steer you to talk to your professors and IT department. Their job is to empower your research, not to inhibit it.

Comment: In theory it should be that way, Shouldn't it. But its not how that really works here. Lets leave it at that. You have given me some interesting leads I'll explore them and see if i can get somewhere.
Thanks for your time and the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know your situation, so sorry to bring the mood down.  Just a pet peeve of mine when people assume IT folks don't want to help out. I'd go ahead and plug in your laptop. While the domain controller won't give you access to stuff, the routers and switches will.  Go ahead and use explorer to look around and see if you can find the NAS.  More likely than not, it's just a simple file share.  In that case, double click on it and Windows will prompt you for credentials.  Here is the gotcha.

Comment: When you type in your credentials, make sure to prepend your userid with the school's domain name.  Like my university was `UGAEDU\_userid_` , the same user id to log into the computer lab.  Use the same password.  The NAS will verify your credentials with the Domain Controller and grant you access if you are successful.